# Proving a (little) statement involving the counting measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{P}(X),\#)$ where $X\neq \emptyset$. The counting measure is given by$$\mu : \mathcal{P}(X) \to [0,\infty], \, \mu(A)=\begin{cases}|A|  \, \,  \, \text{ if A is finite} \\ +\infty \text{ if A is infinte}\end{cases}$$

**Statement:**

Let $f: X\to \mathbb{R}$ be a measureable function is integratable with respect to $(X,\mathcal{P}(X),\#)$, iff there is at most a countable set $J\subseteq X$ with $f|_{X\setminus J}\equiv 0$ and $\sum _{j\in J}|f(j)|<\infty$

**My idea:**

"$\Rightarrow$"

I feel like this can easier proven when looking at the negated statement. So, let $f: X\to \mathbb{R}$ be measurable with respect to   $(X,\mathcal{P}(X),\#)$. Assume that there is at least one countable set  $J\subseteq X$ with $f|_{X\setminus J}\equiv 0$ and $\sum _{j\in J}|f(j)|<\infty$.

But I am getting nowhere, sadly. Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this? I feel like this isn't really that hard of a question which makes me even more furious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that for any finite $J\subseteq X$, $\sum_{j\in J} \vert f(j)\vert$ is a simple function and is equal to its integral under the counting measure.

If $f\neq 0$ on an uncountable set, then by cardinality considerations, there exists some $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\vert f(j)\vert\geq \frac{1}{k}$ for infinitely many $j$-s. This would contardict the integrability. Indeed one can write
$$\{ \vert f\vert \neq 0 \}= \underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty}{\cup}}\Big\{ \vert f\vert \geq \frac{1}{k} \Big\} , $$
and since the LHS is of uncountable cardinality, at least one the sets in the RHS must also be uncountable, and in particular infinite.

You then have $J\subseteq X$ countable such that $\vert f(j)\vert$ only if $j\in J$. You just have to verify that the supremum of integrals of simple functions is exactly $\sum _{j\in J}|f(j)|$.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What do you mean by "cardinality considerations"?

Comment: I've added an edit.